# How to reply location with coords in telegraf bot?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet, telegram, telegraf

How to reply location with coords in telegraf bot?

bot.hears(/coords (.+)/, (ctx) => ctx.replyWithLocation(ctx.message.location.latitude+','+ctx.message.location.longitude))

example : /coords 40.123456, 1.123456

telegram bot : view map

Coords introducing with keyboard in telegram, and view map Next.

What is Code in telegraf bot.hears??

Something like:

Bot: introducing coords?

User: 41.123,2.123

Bot: view map

bot.hears(/coords (.+)/, (ctx) => ctx.replyWithLocation(ctx.message.location.latitude+','+ctx.message.location.longitude))

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctx.telegram.sendLocation` method :

```
bot.command("/sendlocation", (ctx) => {
  bot.ctx.telegram.sendLocation(chat id , latitude, longitude)
)}
```